# Ohmic losses in interconnected DC link

Tags: power, dc

I understand the ohmic losses are equal to I^2 * R where R is the resistance of the cable, but why are  these losses usually never doubled to account for the return path conductor (assuming 2 wire connecting 2 DC stages) if the resistance is only given by for one wire?

Or is the resistance by convention the sum of resistances of the incoming and return path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Or is the resistance by convention the sum of resistances of the
> incoming and return path?*

It is indeed the sum of the resistances for forward and return paths.